Not able to SSH to ubuntu cloud jammy
Not very good at linux but just deployed a cloud img of jammy ubuntu and i want to ssh to it using password authentication
Getting a disconnected message after pressing enter on the username and it says server refused , public key
I have changed the sshd_config "PasswordAuthentication yes" and rebooted but still no good
Any ideas ?

run ssh with -vvv, edit your question and add the command you'Re running and its output.

What file did you configure PasswordAuthentication yes? Please show the full path.
